# Equivalence of two elements of the free group under automorphisms?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I have two elements of the form
$$
w = x_1^{a_1} x_2^{a_2} x_3^{a_3} x_4^{a_4} x_5^{a_5} x_6^{a_6}
$$
and
$$
w' = x_1^{b_1} x_2^{b_2} x_3^{b_3} x_4^{b_4} x_5^{b_5} x_6^{b_6}
$$
for integers $a_i$ and $b_j$ where the $a_i$ are the same as the $b_j$ as multisets and I'd like to know if there is always an automorphism of $F_6$ sending $w$ to $w'$.  Is this the case?  For example, if in $F_2$ I knew that $x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}$ and $x_2^{a_2}x_1^{a_1}$ were always related by an automorphism, I'd be all set.

Edit: In my original question I asked for about the existence of an algorithm to tell if two words in a free group differ by applying an automorphism.  This is completely answered by Whitehead's algorithm, as Derek Holt pointed out.  I'm still interested in the question regarding the specific elements that I list here, hence the edit.  To be even more concrete, how about the elements
$$
w = x_1^2 x_2^2 x_3^3 x_4^3 x_5^5 x_6^5
$$
and
$$
w' = x_1^3 x_2^2 x_3^5 x_4^3 x_5^5 x_6^2
$$
in $F_6$.

Comment: Yes, it's called the [Whitehead Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead%27s_algorithm)

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you very much, I somehow completely did not know about the Whitehead algorithm.  Do you happen to know if it is implemented somewhere?  I saw [this package](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/fga/doc/manual.pdf) but unfortunately it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: I am finding your questions confusing. You haven't said what $x_1,\ldots,x_6$ are. Also, in $x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}$ and $x_2^{a_2}x_1^{a_1}$ are conjugate, so they are obvioulsy related by an automorphism.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh sorry - they are the generators fro the free group $F_6$.  Although your comment about those being conjugate completely answers my question (somehow I just didn't see that).  Thanks!

Comment: Well I don't think that I have answered the question for the words in $x_1,\ldots,x_6$.

Comment: @DerekHolt You can first swap the orders of the $x_i$ so that the exponents agree and then you can permute the indices of the generators.